# How can I customize Repl.it to not use poetry?

Tags: python, replit

I am trying to create a Repl.it on my Python project, and when I run, it fails at not finding `[tool.poetry]` section. And yes my project has a `pyproject.toml` file.

```
Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> /usr/local/bin/python3 -m poetry add halo vistir distlib click packaging tomlkit pip-shims pythonfinder python-cfonts appdirs

[RuntimeError]
[tool.poetry] section not found in pyproject.toml

add [-D|--dev] [--git GIT] [--path PATH] [-E|--extras EXTRAS] [--optional] [--python PYTHON] [--platform PLATFORM] [--allow-prereleases] [--dry-run] [--] <name> (<name>)...

exit status 1


Repl.it: Package operation failed.
```

The question is, how can I know what is happening in the initializing stage, how does it know what dependencies to install and how can I change the behavior? You can try this repo: `github/frostming/pdm` for reproduction.

Answer (score 4):

After importing project you could specify `run` button behaviour with bash command:

[image]

This will be saved to `.replit`. You could write tings like `pip3 install -r requirements.txt && python3 main.py`. Read more about available settings in [.replit docs](https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/configuring-run-button)

---

Also there is another [doc about dependencies](https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/installing-packages) with following quote:

> In a pyproject.toml file, you list your packages along with other
> details about your project. For example, consider the following
> snippet from pyproject.toml:
>
> ```
> ...
> [tool.poetry.dependencies]
> python = "^3.8"
> flask = "^1.1"
> ...
> ```